# Firebase consecutive upload stops midway, only upload last image

Tags: swift, firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage

I'm having trouble uploading an array of images to Firebase storage in Swift.
I have this function:

```
func uploadImages(ref: FIRStorageReference, data: Data, completionHandler: @escaping imagesHandler) {

    let task = ref.put(data)

    let observer = task.observe(.progress) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot.progress!)
    }

    task.observe(.success) { (snapshot) in
        if let url = snapshot.metadata {

            if let link = url.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {

                completionHandler(link)
            }else {

                completionHandler(nil)
            }
        }else {

            completionHandler(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

which I use here:

```
var downloadURLImages = [String]()

for each in itemImage {

    self.uploadImages(ref: self.inventoryStorageRef, data: each, completionHandler: { (links) in
        if let url = links {

            downloadURLImages.append(url)
        }
    })
}
```

The problem is, I get the download URLs, but it only uploads the last image of the array. On the first function, I put an observer to see what's happening and below is the result.

With 2 images being uploaded:

```
<NSProgress: 0x60000052b2c0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 41605  
<NSProgress: 0x60000052a5a0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0026 / Completed: 108 of 41713  
<NSProgress: 0x608000135f40> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1990 / Completed: 8300 of 41713  
<NSProgress: 0x608000135f40> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 41713 of 41713  
<NSProgress: 0x60000052a640> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 41713 of 41713
```

With 4 images being uploaded:

```
<NSProgress: 0x600000520280> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 41605  
<NSProgress: 0x600000527580> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 29438  
<NSProgress: 0x60000052b5e0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 29438  
<NSProgress: 0x60000052a5a0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 41605  
<NSProgress: 0x600000527800> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 41605  
<NSProgress: 0x60000052b7c0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0026 / Completed: 108 of 41713  
<NSProgress: 0x60000052aaa0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0037 / Completed: 108 of 29546  
<NSProgress: 0x60000052b7c0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0037 / Completed: 108 of 29546  
<NSProgress: 0x60000052ab40> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0026 / Completed: 108 of 41713  
<NSProgress: 0x60000052ab40> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0026 / Completed: 108 of 41713  
<NSProgress: 0x60000052c1c0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1990 / Completed: 8300 of 41713  
<NSProgress: 0x60000052c1c0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 41713 of 41713  
<NSProgress: 0x60000052c1c0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1990 / Completed: 8300 of 41713  
<NSProgress: 0x6080001381a0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 41713 of 41713  
<NSProgress: 0x60000052c6c0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2809 / Completed: 8300 of 29546  
<NSProgress: 0x60000052c6c0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1990 / Completed: 8300 of 41713  
<NSProgress: 0x60000052c760> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 41713 of 41713  
<NSProgress: 0x608000139000> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2809 / Completed: 8300 of 29546  
<NSProgress: 0x608000136ee0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2809 / Completed: 8300 of 29546  
<NSProgress: 0x60000052b180> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2809 / Completed: 8300 of 29546  
<NSProgress: 0x60000052c120> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 41713 of 41713  
<NSProgress: 0x608000139280> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 41713 of 41713  
<NSProgress: 0x60000052bb80> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 41713 of 41713
```

Only the last image is uploaded completely.

What should I do?

Comment: are you providing different names to image ? you are just putting data on server I think using putData and everytime data is being replaced with the new value as name is not provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code

```
 func uploadImages(ref: FIRStorageReference, data: Data, completionHandler: @escaping imagesHandler) {
        let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
        let task = ref.child("\(imageName).png").putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (snapshot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                    completionHandler(nil)
                }
            })

    let observer = task.observe(.progress) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot.progress!)
    }

    task.observe(.success) { (snapshot) in
        if let url = snapshot.metadata {

            if let link = url.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {

                completionHandler(link)
            }else {

                completionHandler(nil)
            }
        }else {

            completionHandler(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome.. Happy to help :)